# Getting 'Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected' on mockito tests

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have the following Unit test:

```
@InjectMocks
private PaymentTicketService paymentTicketService;

@Test
public void blahblahTest() {

    ...

    String spokesmanDocumentNumber = "47246536809";
    PaymentTicketPdfResponse paymentTicketPdfResponse = Fixture.from(...).gimme(...);
   
    when(paymentTicketService.generatePaymentTicket(any(GeneratePaymentTicketRequest.class), spokesmanDocumentNumber)).thenReturn(paymentTicketPdfResponse);

    ...
}
```

The testing method is this one:

```
public PaymentTicketPdfResponse generatePaymentTicket(GeneratePaymentTicketRequest generateBankTicketRequest, String spokesmanDocumentNumber) {
    ...
}
```

I'm getting a `Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected` error on the 'when' clause of my test. It says that I cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
I don't really understand this error, as I'm passing any(GeneratePaymentTicketRequest.class) and a acctual string to the mocked method.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix matchers and actual values. Wrap the value in a matcher:

`when(paymentTicketService.generatePaymentTicket(any(GeneratePaymentTicketRequest.class), eq(spokesmanDocumentNumber))).thenReturn(paymentTicketPdfResponse);`